# Text not showing on my Button- Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, button

I'm new to Android studio, and I need to write something on the Button here but the text doesn't show, what can I do to solve this?

Note that the `LinearLayout` showed in the code is placed inside another bigger `LinearLayout`.

```xml
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/datee"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"
                    android:text="hiiii"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"></Button>
    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:text="Auction date: "
                        android:id="@+id/done"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to tune padding and margin of button

Comment: Can you share the whole xml file?

Comment: @tataelm the code is so long I can't post it in a comment

Comment: Try removing the background attribute i.e android:background="@drawable/yellow_border" . If that works you use the material outlined button style to have a yellow border.

Comment: I tried the above code and it works fine. Of course I cannot test the yellow_border background. Can you send an image how it looks on your device?

Comment: I removed the backgroud and the text showed but I don't Know what's wrong with the yellow_border , here it is: `code` ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/transparent"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topRightRadius="12dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/yellow"
        android:width="1dp"/>
</shape> `

Answer (score 2):

you can use somthing like this

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/datee"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="hiiii"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

and try to change the `android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"`

because you might have some padding inside of it